# How to Render HTML with Javascript Chart to PDF Using iText?

Tags: javascript, html, itext

does anyones knouw how to render a html document with javascript chart to PDF using iText?
if you thinks it's can't be done... plz tell me... 
so I don't have to waste my time

Comment: You want to render an HTML document that uses a dynamically generated javascript chart as a PDF on the server (not the client)? Aside from "printing" the HTML document ... that's not viable. I mean, anything can be done programmatically, but what you describe is like "I want to eat the peanut butter cookies that I make using oatmeal cookie dough"...

Comment: ow...
but if we can render the chart in the html as an image, and then use iText to create PDF from that, don't you think it's became viable... ?

Answer (score 0):

not tested for rendering charts, but you can try iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser and its HTMLWorker.ParseToList method.